# Off-line using of online maps

Tags: image-processing, offline, offline-mode

Does somebody know soft for better using online maps in off-line mode?
Because, you know, now you have to do several printscreens and then glue them.

But I'm pretty sure that there is tool at least for gluing overlapping images

Answer (score 1):

[MapsWithMe](http://www.mapswithme.com) provides free offline maps for iPhone, iPad and Android. iOS version is [available at the AppStore](http://www.mapswithme.com/iphone-app). Android is in beta, just ask for it at info@mapswithme.com

Comment: Or Android tablet. MapsWithMe is available for Android as well now: http://market.android.com/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps

Answer (score 0):

in Russia, there are Yandex maps and the collection of cache maps (http://ymm.sytes.net/) which you can load in your cell phone. Unfortunately, as I know, there is only Russian interface.